# Boxify feature for popup in openlayers

Tags: openlayers

Is it possible to give effect of boxify and animations for a popup in openlayer??
I have anchoredPopup .

```
var Popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.Anchored("popupId");
```

I know that display class of this is olPopup . But how to give those effects?

Answer (score 0):

For this u can use [gxp](https://github.com/opengeo/gxp) or ExtJs. gxp more simply that ExtJs but ExtJs give u more options.